# This is regarding the state management in Riverpod and the warning about setter/getter

Tags: flutter, dart, state, riverpod

I'm using Riverpod for state management in Flutter, but when I wrote the following code, I received a warning `use_setters_to_change_properties` for the part of the code where the function `setDay` is used. It suggests using setters when you're just assigning a value.

```dart
final sampleProvider = StateNotifierProvider<SampleNotifier, int>((ref) {
  return SampleNotifier();
});

class SampleNotifier extends StateNotifier<int> {
  SampleNotifier() : super(0);
  void setDay({required int day}) {
    state = day;
  }
}
```

However, when I made the modifications to use setters as suggested by the warning, I now receive another warning called `avoid_setters_without_getters` that advises against using setters without getters. And when I use getters, I get yet another warning called `unnecessary_getters_setters` that discourages the use of simple getters/setters that only get and set values. All I want to do is assign an `int` value and trigger a redraw of the screen.

How can I eliminate the `use_setters_to_change_properties` warning without triggering the other warnings? I prefer not to make changes to the lint rules or stop using Riverpod.

[unnecessary_getters_setters](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/unnecessary_getters_setters)

[avoid_setters_without_getters](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/avoid_setters_without_getters)

[use_setters_to_change_properties](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/use_setters_to_change_properties)

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, I don't quite understand your advice. Are you suggesting that it's better not to use StateNotifier?

Comment: Yes.  Use the modern notifiers and providers.  Legacy notifiers and providers have fundamental limitations and lead to fragile code.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer at this point to simply ignore this lint in this line:

```
class SampleNotifier extends StateNotifier<int> {
  SampleNotifier() : super(0);
  // ignore: use_setters_to_change_properties
  void setDay({required int day}) {
    state = day;
  }
}
```

As a result, other warnings will not appear and this rule will not apply to other parts of the code. win-win

I also want to add that your `setDay()` method will probably be much more complex and with more logic a little later. And then you will simply remove this comment.